# Does AWS ECR provide automated docker image build option?

Tags: github, dockerhub, docker-build, amazon-ecr, docker-push

`dockerhub` provides automated build option on every new `git push`.

### [image]

---

With automated build option,

- we know, which image corresponds to which docker filethis is a important.
- On `git push` of `Dockerfile` in GitHub repo or Bitbucket, build starts immediately.

---

1)

Does AWS ECR provide such automated build option? because I don't prefer the approach of running `docker push` through some automation

2)

if yes, can the automated build support  `docker-compose build`?

Answer (score 2):

ECR does not contain a build tool. But you can use AWS Codebuild AWS's continuous integration tool. I am pretty sure it supports both of your requirements.

Comment: How is this better than Jenkins CI?

Comment: I am not sure since I haven't used Jenkins for a long time. What I could think of as an advantage when running codebuild is that it has better access to aws tools such as S3, elasticbeanstalk, cloudformation etc since it runs from inside the aws echo systems.